# WCF - return multiple records

Tags: wcf, datatable, records

Last week I created an asmx web service which returns multiple rows using soap.

I now moving onto WCF and am wanting to do the same.

In my ASMX web service I am doing the following..

```
public class sample
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameOfFile { get; set; }
    //public int Distance { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public sample[] Test(int count, float lat, float lng)
{
    DataTable dt = new Gallery().DisplayNearestByLatLong(count, lat, lng);
    var samples = new List<sample>();

    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        var s = new sample();
        s.Id = item[0].ToString();
        s.Name = item[1].ToString();
        s.NameOfFile = item[2].ToString();
        //s.Distance = (int)item[3];

        samples.Add(s);
    }
    return samples.ToArray();
}
```

This code works great but now I want to do the same but using WCF.

My current WCF files look like this (I copied a tutorial but have setup the data contract (which i think is needed?))

```
GalleryWebService.cs
public class GalleryWebService : IGalleryWebService
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        return composite;
    }

    public CompositeType GetTestData()
    {
        return new CompositeType();
    }
}
```

**IGalleryWebService.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGalleryWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "test/random")]
    CompositeType GetTestData();
}

[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    [DataMember]
    string _id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    string _name = "Hello";
    public string Name
    {
       get { return _name; }
       set { _name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    string _nameoffile = "Hello";
    public string NameOfFile
    {
       get { return _nameoffile; }
       set { _nameoffile = value; }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to go about doing it and how? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF has not so many differences:

```
[DataContract]
public class sample
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string NameOfFile { get; set; }
}
```

`DataMember` attributes are not set by default, so they are obligatory somehow.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGalleryWebService
{

    [OperationContract]
    sample[] Test(int count, float lat, float lng);
}
```

Moreover, if you use `basicHttpBinding` and add link using "Add Web reference" (instead of service reference) - you will receive the same result as you would have if you used asmx service.

Comment: O.k, i've implemented that but when I put it on my live IIS web server it doesn't work. This is only when I put DataTable in. Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: I'm getting the error.. IIS specified authentication schemes 'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.

Comment: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> IIS -> Select a web site or an applciation -> Double click on Authentificcation icon -> disable Integrated Windows authentification

Comment: You can make sure that my solution works if you use asp.net deployment server instead of iis.